# Web Form Builder engine

Tags: webforms

I want to give my users the option to build and save web forms.

Can you please recommend plugins/frameworks/scripts which do that?

Regards,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://neyric.github.io/inputex/

*Putting more text to get to the minimum requirements...*