# End-user authoring of multi-page form using Javascript and Php

Tags: php, javascript, webforms

I want to allow my users to create multi-page forms. So, on the basis of selection of for example a dropdown list of multiple choices, the user can author the multiple pages of the form itself and store their created forms in the server. The functionality similar to Google Forms in GDocs. Is there any example available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Form Builder engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026899/web-form-builder-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You might have a look at phpgem (which generates a form definition for a defined database) or phpmyadmin (again, this generates a form from a database - but on the fly). Or there's tools like [phpeanuts](http://www.phppeanuts.org), [phplens](http://phplens.com/) and [PfP Studio](http://pfp-studio.sourceforge.net/) but these aimed at developers.